# Solving $\dot{x} = -\pi\dfrac{A}{k}\sin(kx)\cos(\pi y),$ $\dot{y} = A\cos(kx)\sin(\pi y)$

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems

The following system is given:
$$\dot{x} = -\pi\dfrac{A}{k}\sin(kx)\cos(\pi y)$$
$$\dot{y} = A\cos(kx)\sin(\pi y)$$
How can I find the parametric representation $x(t)$, $y(t)$?

Comment: does $\dot{x}$ mean $\frac{dx}{dt} ?$

Comment: Are you sure that you really need this? I mean, is that a problem in textbook or is it a part of another question?

Answer (score 3):

You can first compute the ratio
\begin{equation}
\frac{\dot{x}}{\dot{y}} = -\dfrac{\pi}{k} \frac{\tan(kx)}{\tan(\pi y)}
\end{equation}
Which you rearrange as:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\dot{x}}{\tan(kx)} =-\dfrac{\pi}{k} \frac{\dot{y}}{\tan(\pi y)}
\end{equation}
Then you look for the solution of the system given by the two equations:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\dot{x}}{\tan(kx)} =K
\end{equation}
And
\begin{equation}
-\dfrac{\pi}{k} \frac{\dot{y}}{\tan(\pi y)}=K
\end{equation}
where K is a constant independent of x and y.The it is possible to solve the differential equations. For instance the first equation has solution
\begin{equation}
x(t)=\frac{1}{k} \arcsin(e^{k(K t +c_1)})
\end{equation}
where $c_1$ is the integration constant.A siilar result is obtained for the second equation.

Comment: Why would $K$ be a constant?